# Using Flutter Git submodule in flutter project

Tags: flutter, git, git-submodules

I have a main project folder name **tc_showcase** in that folder we have two folders one is  flutter application name **tc_mob_ui** and other folder name is **submodule** may have multiple flutter module and oner of the module is **qpf_core** and want to use flutter module in **tc_mob_ui**.

I did clone submodule by running command

```
farahanaansari foundation % git submodule add https://github.com/xyz/qpf_core.git submodules/qpf_core
```

My Folder structure

[image]

Using local submodule like that but not able to import module file

[image]

Comment: @jamesdlin want to use submodule in myapp application.

Comment: And what problem are you encountering?

Comment: you should just do it

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi my_new_package: 
         path: ./my_new_package. then to get the path of submodule

Comment: Is there a reason why you instead don't just add a direct git dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`?  https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

Comment: It's more common to add your local dependencies as sibling folders of your main folder and then refer to them as `path: ../other_name` . For example you might have `.../source/main_project` and `.../source/sub_package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `pubspec.yaml` you should try this:

```
...
qp_mobile_app_foundation:
  path: ../submodules/qpf_core
...
```

and be sure qpf_core is separate flutter project like
[image]

More info [Dependencies on unpublished packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

Comment: i did it still not importing

Comment: I've updated my answer, but if it will not work, you should provide what is you qpf_core submodule is.

Comment: Wouldn't that have to be `./submodules/qpf_core` not `../submodules/qpf_core`?

Comment: I don't think so: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages,
but everything is possible :)